# Handling An AsyncTask when the user hits the home button

Tags: android, asynchronous

I have a possibly long download/unzip task that occurs when the user hits an app's splash Activity. It is encapsulated in an object's method `InitSync.getInitialData()` which sets up and displays a corresponding progressDialog and manages the progress of the task.

When the user hits the home button the task continues to run, but when they return to the app a new `InitSync` object gets created and it kicks off a second download while the first is running.

How can I get a reference to the original instance of InitSync, which allows me to prevent a 2nd `AsyncTask` from firing?

Comment: If the data really takes a long time, then it'd probably be better to get the data via `Service` and let it store the data in a file or SQL database. It will continue to download in the background while the user is not looking at the app.  If the data is not there, pop up your dialog. If it is, continue with the app.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: The issue isn't the time as even on a short download, the user could still navigate away from the activity.

Comment: Right.  The real issue is trying to get a reference to an object that has no guarantee of existing when the user comes back to the app (in one minute, two minutes, an hour, day, week, or year later).  When the user presses the "home" button, the OS pretty much takes control of it's memory and could dump it at any time.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, the only option is to cancel and restart the download or finish it in the background via Service.  You can't trust an AsyncTask or any object to stick around once the user leaves the app for anything.